# calling a function within a settimeout function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

To provide breather to my recursive javascript i was trying to to use a delay for not letting script crash in the browser.

Here is piece of code that is used to call the function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
       recursiveGenerateTree(objNode.NodeList[cntLi], spnApplyClass, '', objEditParam)
}, 50);
```

It appears that the function is not getting called, any way out for this

Comment: For the future, please format your code so it's not all on one line and therefore is easily readable.

Comment: Have you tried running it under FireBug, or Chrome's Script debugger, or even IE's Dev-tool (F12)?  This should show any javascript errors that may be occurring.

Comment: Please check the errors.

Comment: "Is not working" isn't very helpful. Same is true for your 3 lines of code.

Comment: Are you saying that that code appears inside (at the end?) of your `recursiveGenerateTree()` function? (Hence the pseudo-recursion?) Please show the surrounding code.

Comment: No there is no error in error console of FF.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes you are correct it is inside a function from where recursion is initiating.

Comment: Do you need me to post some more code.

Answer (score 1):

try changing 50 to a larger value...the value is in milliseconds..try using 1000 or 2000 instead of 50.

Answer (score 1):

**setTimeout** calls a function once after the interval and then doesn't call it back. i think its better to use **setInterval**. Then the function will be called in the intervals.

You can try

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   setInterval(function () {
       recursiveGenerateTree(objNode.NodeList[cntLi], spnApplyClass, '', objEditParam)
   }, 50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason this might be happening is that your `objNode` is null, and so when the function is preparing to invoke, its evaluation stops it. To explain better, before the `recursiveGenerateTree` function is invoked, its arguments need to be evaluated first. If the aforementioned symbol is null, its member access `.NodeList[cntLi]` will fail.

Comment: I have checked that objNode.NodeList[cntLi] is not null.

Comment: Have you checked it from within the `setTimeout` function, or before it's invoked?

Comment: I have checked it within setTimeout function

Comment: Do the same for the `recursiveGenerateTree` function itself. Perhaps by using `setTimout` and thus changing the context of your execution (the anonymous function will execute in the context of `window`), the function cannot be located any longer.

Answer (score -3):

I guess you have to put the function outside of the setTimeOut

Something like this :

```
function myfunction(){
  recursiveGenerateTree(objNode.NodeList[cntLi], spnApplyClass, '', objEditParam)
}

setTimeout( myfunction , 50);
```

Comment: This does not change anything.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: oh ok then ignore this answer.